# executable not found on docker container

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm having some issue trying to run a `CMD` command inside a docker container with a Go application.

This is the output I've got:

```
golang-api | /bin/sh: ./server: not found
golang-api exited with code 127
```

This is the Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.18-alpine

RUN apk add g++ && apk add make

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN make build

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ./server
```

And this is the Makefile responsible for the build command:

```
LINUX_AMD64 = GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=1 GO111MODULE=on

migrate:
    cd cmd/migrations/$(FOLDER) && go run main.go

build:
    cd cmd && $(LINUX_AMD64) go build -a -v -tags musl -o server
```

And the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    container_name: golang-api
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_URL=$POSTGRES_URL

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
```

Complete output:

```
Building api
Sending build context to Docker daemon  74.24kB
Step 1/9 : FROM golang:1.18-alpine
 ---> 6078a5fce1f5
Step 2/9 : RUN apk add g++ && apk add make
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2a85b9182b80
Step 3/9 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> baf1e6b7047c
Step 4/9 : COPY go.mod go.sum ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1f2d031bc1b0
Step 5/9 : RUN go mod download
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 471d6f24e6a9
Step 6/9 : COPY . .
 ---> eaa86ff7cb1b
Step 7/9 : RUN make build
 ---> Running in d6ae6ce79222
cd cmd && GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=1 GO111MODULE=on go build -a -v -tags musl -o server
internal/goos
internal/goarch
internal/race
internal/unsafeheader
internal/goexperiment
runtime/internal/syscall
internal/cpu
sync/atomic
runtime/internal/atomic
internal/itoa
math/bits
internal/abi
runtime/internal/math
runtime/internal/sys
unicode/utf8
unicode
container/list
crypto/internal/subtle
crypto/subtle
unicode/utf16
vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/cryptobyte/asn1
internal/nettrace
vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/internal/subtle
encoding
github.com/mymachine/my-api/internal/controllers/dto
github.com/mymachine/my-api/internal/controllers/helpers
internal/bytealg
math
runtime
internal/reflectlite
sync
internal/testlog
internal/singleflight
math/rand
runtime/cgo
errors
sort
internal/oserror
strconv
path
vendor/golang.org/x/net/dns/dnsmessage
io
crypto/elliptic/internal/fiat
syscall
golang.org/x/text/internal/tag
hash
bytes
strings
hash/crc32
reflect
crypto
crypto/internal/randutil
crypto/hmac
crypto/rc4
net/http/internal/ascii
vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/hkdf
regexp/syntax
github.com/jackc/chunkreader/v2
bufio
crypto/elliptic/internal/nistec
internal/syscall/unix
time
internal/syscall/execenv
vendor/golang.org/x/text/transform
golang.org/x/crypto/pbkdf2
golang.org/x/text/transform
golang.org/x/text/runes
golang.org/x/text/width
regexp
internal/poll
io/fs
context
github.com/mymachine/my-api/internal/entities
github.com/jackc/pgconn/internal/ctxwatch
embed
os
github.com/jinzhu/inflection
github.com/jinzhu/now
internal/fmtsort
encoding/binary
crypto/ed25519/internal/edwards25519/field
crypto/md5
crypto/sha512
crypto/cipher
crypto/sha256
crypto/sha1
encoding/base64
fmt
internal/godebug
encoding/pem
crypto/ed25519/internal/edwards25519
path/filepath
vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/internal/poly1305
io/ioutil
internal/intern
vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/curve25519/internal/field
vendor/golang.org/x/sys/cpu
net/netip
crypto/aes
crypto/des
vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20
github.com/jackc/pgio
github.com/jackc/pgpassfile
os/exec
os/signal
net
vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305
math/big
encoding/hex
net/url
compress/flate
vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/curve25519
log
vendor/golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm
vendor/golang.org/x/text/unicode/bidi
vendor/golang.org/x/net/http2/hpack
mime
mime/quotedprintable
compress/gzip
net/http/internal
database/sql/driver
github.com/mymachine/my-api/internal/pkg/errors
encoding/json
github.com/jackc/pgservicefile
vendor/golang.org/x/text/secure/bidirule
golang.org/x/text/internal/language
database/sql
golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm
golang.org/x/text/unicode/bidi
vendor/golang.org/x/net/idna
os/user
crypto/rand
encoding/asn1
crypto/dsa
crypto/elliptic
crypto/ed25519
crypto/rsa
github.com/jackc/pgproto3/v2
golang.org/x/text/internal/language/compact
golang.org/x/text/secure/bidirule
github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/internal/sanitize
golang.org/x/text/language
go/token
vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/cryptobyte
crypto/x509/pkix
gorm.io/gorm/utils
gorm.io/gorm/logger
encoding/gob
go/scanner
golang.org/x/text/internal
github.com/joho/godotenv
crypto/ecdsa
go/ast
golang.org/x/text/cases
github.com/joho/godotenv/autoload
golang.org/x/text/secure/precis
gorm.io/gorm/clause
gorm.io/gorm/schema
gorm.io/gorm
net/textproto
vendor/golang.org/x/net/http/httpproxy
github.com/google/uuid
crypto/x509
github.com/jackc/pgtype
mime/multipart
vendor/golang.org/x/net/http/httpguts
crypto/tls
gorm.io/gorm/migrator
gorm.io/gorm/callbacks
net/http/httptrace
github.com/jackc/pgconn
net/http
github.com/jackc/pgconn/stmtcache
github.com/jackc/pgx/v4
github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/stdlib
gorm.io/driver/postgres
github.com/mymachine/my-api/internal/infrastructure/repository
github.com/mymachine/my-api/configs
github.com/mymachine/my-api/internal/services
github.com/mymachine/my-api/internal/services/transaction
github.com/mymachine/my-api/internal/controllers/handlers/health
github.com/gorilla/mux
github.com/mymachine/my-api/internal/controllers/handlers/transaction
github.com/mymachine/my-api/internal/router
github.com/mymachine/my-api/cmd
Removing intermediate container d6ae6ce79222
 ---> 621aa6a266de
Step 8/9 : EXPOSE 8000
 ---> Running in 3cbd17d32c37
Removing intermediate container 3cbd17d32c37
 ---> 754f71a7753e
Step 9/9 : CMD ./server
 ---> Running in dfcdc8cd45ce
Removing intermediate container dfcdc8cd45ce
 ---> 511dbf89a001
Successfully built 511dbf89a001
Successfully tagged my-api_api:latest
Creating my-api_db_1 ... done
Creating golang-api            ... done
Attaching to my-api_db_1, golang-api
golang-api | /bin/sh: ./server: not found
```

Comment: could you add tree output ?

Comment: output added @paltaa

Comment: I think that using cd in the make build command is generating the file in the wrong place, could you try to use go build instead of make build and pass as an argument the file path and paste the output?

Comment: trying with "RUN cd cmd && go build -o server" instead of the "make build" the result was exactly the same. @paltaa

Comment: Yes, remove the cd and pass the file as an argument to go build

Comment: now it worked : ) I tried "RUN go build cmd/main.go" Thank you so much @paltaa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249877/discussion-between-joao-and-paltaa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved.

Somehow,the `RUN cd cmd` command seemed not generating the file in the expected directory.

Trying with `RUN go build cmd/main.go` instead of using the **makefile** worked, as well pointed by @paltaa in the comments.